# Table has no (public) columns on Xamarin PCL project Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1, sqlite.net

I receive this error below, on build to Windows Phone 8.1, it's a PCL project in Xamarin with Visual Studio 2015, someone help me?

I searched on Google and this is a error Linker in iOS, but I have deploy/build to Windows Phone 8.1 this not make sense.

```
System.Exception: Table has no (public) columns
   at SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection.CreateTable(Type ty, CreateFlags createFlags)
   at SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection.CreateTable[T](CreateFlags createFlags)
```

[The print/image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpAt7.png)

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Android. Did you figured it out?